# Firebase not connecting With the react-app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-realtime-database

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react"
import { Form, Button, Card, Alert } from "react-bootstrap"
import { useAuth } from "../contexts/AuthContext"
import { Link, useNavigate} from "react-router-dom"

export default function Signup() {
  const emailRef = useRef()
  const passwordRef = useRef()
  const passwordConfirmRef = useRef()
  const { signup } = useAuth()
  const [error, setError] = useState("")
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  const history = useNavigate()

  async function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    if (passwordRef.current.value !== passwordConfirmRef.current.value) {
      return setError("Passwords do not match")
    }

    try {
      setError("")
      setLoading(true)
      await signup(emailRef.current.value, passwordRef.current.value)
      history.push("/")
    } catch {
      setError("Failed to create an account")
    }

    setLoading(false)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Card>
        <Card.Body>
          <h2 className="text-center mb-4">Sign Up</h2>
          {error && <Alert variant="danger">{error}</Alert>}
          <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Form.Group id="email">
              <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control type="email" ref={emailRef} required />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group id="password">
              <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control type="password" ref={passwordRef} required />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group id="password-confirm">
              <Form.Label>Password Confirmation</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control type="password" ref={passwordConfirmRef} required />
            </Form.Group>
            <Button disabled={loading} className="w-100" type="submit">
              Sign Up
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </Card.Body>
      </Card>
      <div className="w-100 text-center mt-2">
        Already have an account? <Link to="/login">Log In</Link>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

I am trying to make a signup page with is connected with my firebase.js file but whenever I try to create an user it always throws an error "Failed to create an account".

What I tried was:

- Changed the auth keys
- Removed or Added local host again in users of firebase
- Still problem persists

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from "react"
import { auth } from "../firebase"

const AuthContext = React.createContext()

export function useAuth() {
    return useContext(AuthContext)
  }

export function AuthProvider({ children }) { 
    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState()
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)


    function signup(email, password) {
        return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            setCurrentUser(user)
            setLoading(false)
        })

        return unsubscribe
    }, [])

    const value = {
        currentUser,
        // login,
        signup,
        // logout,
        // resetPassword,
        // updateEmail,
        // updatePassword
      }
    

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
            {!loading && children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )

}
```

Here Is my AuthContext.js file But still unsure about it.

and Below is my firebase.js file.

```
import "firebase/auth"
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";

import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";


const app = initializeApp({
    apiKey: 
    authDomain: ,
    projectId: ,
    storageBucket: ,
    messagingSenderId:,
    appId: 
})


export const auth = getAuth(app);
export default app
```

I have removed the creds so I a still unsure about the problem

Comment: Check your `AuthContext` code to ensure the `signup` function is correct. Can you [edit] to add the relevant firebase code you your post so we can see what it's doing?

Comment: @DrewReese Please have a look Drew i have edited the code

Comment: I don't see any overt issues with the frontend UI code. You may need to investigate in firebase to see *why* an account couldn't be created. Maybe one of the Firebase guys will see this post and have a better idea.

Comment: Instead of having an empty `catch`, consider catching the error and logging it, so that you can see what's going wrong: `} catch (e) { console.error(e); setError("Failed to create an account") }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working function to register a new user with firebase. (I put this in a custom hook which I call on the sign-up page).

First, initialize Firebase (I've added the code below for clarity, but would suggest storing it with your firebase config file and importing it to a custom hook)

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const auth = getAuth(app);
```

Function to create a new user. Just pass an object which contains the email, password, etc. from your form when submit.

```
const signUpWithEmailAndPassword = (formData) => {
        const { email, password, displayName } = formData;
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password, displayName)
            .then((userCredential) => {
                // Signed in
                const user = userCredential?.user;
                const uid = userCredential?.user?.uid;
                    loginService(uid, user); //this is where you would dispatch your login service which can be reused with your other sign-in options (Google/Facebook/etc)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                alert(error.message);
                console.log(
                    'Error Signing Up with Email & Password. Error Message: ',
                    error.message
                );
            });
    };
```

I would also agree with Drew, while the information provided isn't enough to debug your code, the problem seems to be in your Context. I would suggest you try to create a new user with the above function and just log the result, if it works, then you can start debugging your Context.

Good luck!

Comment: The Error in signup page that says "failed yo create a user" is showing even when user is connected

Comment: Is the error an alert on submit?  Are you catching and logging the error as Frank suggested? We need more information for this one...what do the request/response headers look like?  ...I'm assuming you've done this, but you've enabled email and password sign in through your Firebase Console, right?  Have you tried using Google sign in first to maybe figure out if you're dealing with Auth bugs?

Comment: Actually the error was in history.push() i just went through and read various documentations so yes it is solved now

Comment: Ack, I totally see that issue now. `useNavigate` returns a `navigate` function, not a `history` object with a `push` method. In the OP's code `history` ***is*** the `navigate` function, so they should have just called `history("/")` ***or*** named references correctly so the usage is clear.  Glad it is sorted out now.